# Building static library using Xcode 11. Get “error: Unable to find a suitable library in the XCFramework"

Tags: ios, macos, static, frameworks, xcode11

Someone trying to build mac app with ios project?

I succeeded to build xcframework file ‘libjre_emul.xcframework’. My static library project includes ‘libjre_emul.xcframework’. Building the project with iOS device or simulator succeeds.

But for mac app I get a build error

```
error: Unable to find a suitable library in the XCFramework ‘libjre_emul.xcframework’ (in target ‘AirNote’)
```

In ‘libjre_emul.xcframework’ I included binary built for mac too. like a picture I attach below.

[image]

Does someone solve the error? Please share your solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue? Finding the same in my tests